# Doubt In default time to live (TTL) 255?

Tags: routing, ipv4, networking, ping

I know that,The Default Time to live value is 255, each time a ipv4 packet crosses a router that value is decremented by 1.

But,When I ping my adsl router it shows TTL as 64

```
Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
```

There is only one hop b/w by pc to router so my expected TTL is 254 but why here ping shows TTL as 64..

Any help could be appreciated...

Answer (score 11):

Here's a relevant quote from the `ping` manpage:

> TTL DETAILS
>       The TTL value of an IP packet represents the maximum number of IP routers that the packet can go through before being
>       thrown away.  In current practice you can expect each router in the Internet to decrement the TTL field by exactly
>       one.
>
> The TCP/IP specification recommends setting the TTL field for IP packets to 64, but many systems use smaller values
>       (4.3BSD uses 30, 4.2BSD used 15).

And to quote [RFC 1700:](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1700.html)

> The current recommended default time to live (TTL) for the Internet Protocol (IP) is 64.

Comment: if 64 as default.if its cross another hops it decrement as 63,62 etc.. is it correct or its decrement from 254,253...

Comment: The initial value of the TTL field is set by the host transmitting the packet. As stated in this answer, the value varies and is generally left to the operating system. If the initial value is 64 then after it has passed through the first router it drops to 63 as you say. The TTL you are seeing in your ping response is counting down from the default used by the OS on your gateway router. The ICMP echo response is a new packet and will have a fresh TTL filled in, it will not count down from what was left in the TTL from the ICMP echo request.

Comment: @Rusell But what the reason We use TTL as 255 in ipv4

Answer (score 6):

The maximum TTL is 255, but it is not the default. The default value depends on the operating system as you can see [here](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-11&post=Passive-OS-Fingerprinting).

For example, look at pings to 127.0.0.1 in Windows vs Linux:

My windows 7:

[image: Windows ping]

My Linux machine:

[image: Linux ping]

So it seems that you're getting replies from a machine whose default is 64.

Comment: That's incorrect. That's the TTL of the return packet. There's little sense in showing you the TTL of your own packets. For instance, If you ping 8.8.8.8 from a windows machine, you'll get a TTL below 64.

Comment: Ah, I got your point. You're right. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

TTL values are determined by the remote machine. For example, if you ping a Linux machine, its originating TTL value is 64. Depending on how many networks it crosses to get back to you, the TTL is deducted by a value of 1. So if you ping 8.8.8.8, which is Googles nameserver, it has an originating value of 128. By the time it gets back to you, it may have a value of 121 (it does for me). That means it crossed 7 networks to get to me and it was a windows machine.

Common TTL values -
Router - 255
Windows - 128
Linux-Mac - 64